# Building python package with data files and using them

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

I'd like to build a python package from the following directory:

```
my_package/
        main_funcs.py
        extra_funcs.py
        data/
                data_file.dat
```

so that extra_funcs.py is used in main_funcs.py, and also gets data from data_file.dat.
I'd like to eventually have a .whl and a .tar.gz files for exporting the package.
How can I do that?
I didnt understand how to create them with setuptools, or how to add non-code files on pip build.
Also, I'm not sure how to call the data files from inside the code after the packing.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried to do and what the result was. What are the specific barriers you are running in to? What you're looking to do is a multi step problem, but SO is meant to solve relatively narrow issues, not provide broad code tutorials..

Comment: Check [_setuptools_' `package_data`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) to make sure the additional data are packaged and installed correctly, and then check [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/importlib.resources.html) to read the files once installed (i.e. at run-time).